# Store images in array PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm really new at php just doing some work, I want to save images in a php array and then show them in the screen, but I cannot save them or display them.

```
<?php 
$min = 1;
$max = 9;
$number1 = rand($min,$max);

for ($i=1 ; $i<=$number1 ; $i++){

$firstN [$i] = echo "<img src='index.jpg' border='0'>";
}   


echo $firstN [1];
?>
```

This is what I got , and the last line is to test it but nothing works, I google the topic but it doesn't help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong - `$firstN [$i]` should be `$firstN[$i]` (without the space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `index.jpg` is in the same directory as your file, this should work:

```
<?php 
$firstN = array();
$min = 1;
$max = 9;
$number1 = rand($min, $max);
for ($i = 0; $i < $number1; $i++){
    $firstN[] = '<img src="index.jpg" border="0">';
}   

echo $firstN[0];
?>
```

Cleaned up the code a bit. When storing information in the array, you don't use `echo` and, like Mister pointed out, you had a space in the echo at the bottom of the code between the array-variable and the brackets.

Comment: @MisterMelancholy - Sorry, you beat me to it. Added information now.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and removed my comment. One last thing I noticed though - Your array start at 0, and the original array started at 1. You should probably state that somewhere and point out that `$min` should be changed to 0 (else image 0 will never be displayed)

Comment: @MisterMelancholy - I just changed how the array stores the images. It started at 1, but it normally starts at 0. The variable `$number1` does not say anything about if the image with index 0 should be displayed, but how many images should be added to the loop. As it is right now it will add anything from 1 to 9. I changed the forloop to start at 0 and doing a lesser than rather than lesser or equal. The code is the same, just adding the images at index 0 instead of 1, the loop itself will be executed just like in OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for your help I realized what was wrong with this, I'm having some troubles with the syntax.